# GCP Java dev_appserver Can't make API call memcache.Get in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, google-cloud-code, gcloud-java

I've just migrated a hefty 50k lines codebase from the java8 runtime to the java17 runtime. We are using the updated `appengine-api-1.0-sdk.jar` library provided in the migration guide.

I'm getting an issue on the DEVELOPMENT server only. These issues DO NOT happen when deployed to GCP App Engine.

`Can't make API call memcache.Get in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager`

FYI, we DO NOT invoke Memcache at all anywhere in the codebase. This is getting invoked in the library as far as I can tell. And I do think its a BUG, though I do hope there is a workaround. I also believe this restriction was not enforced in java8, but now is in java17. And some internal broken behaviour has arisen from it.

I have tried using 2 separate dev_appservers. The latest dev_appserver packaged with the GCloud CLI. And an older archived version provided in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/tools/using-local-server) for java8 runtimes. Both return the same result.

`λ  mvn clean package appengine:run -DskipTests`

`λ  ./bin/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/bin/dev_appserver.sh target/core-1.0.1/`

We also have EE8 enabled.

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>com.celbux</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20240205</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.98</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run a servlet:

```json
  ~/dev/repo/Celbux/core  (celbux101)
λ  ./bin/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/bin/dev_appserver.sh target/core-1.0.1/
Warning: unable to determine Java version
Executing [C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot\bin\java, -Dappengine.sdk.root=C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\bin\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java, --add-opens, java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https=ALL-UNNAMED, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -classpath, C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\bin\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar, com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain, --property=kickstart.user.dir=C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core, C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1]
Mar 24, 2024 10:25:02 PM com.google.appengine.init.AppEngineWebXmlInitialParse <init>
INFO: built on 2023-12-28T18:18:01-05:00 from commit ${buildNumber}
Mar 24, 2024 10:25:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\bin\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Mar 24, 2024 10:25:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'appengine.use.EE8', value 'true' with value 'true' from 'C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
2024-03-24 22:25:03.279:INFO :oejs.Server:main: jetty-12.0.5; built: 2023-12-18T14:06:32.502Z; git: 3aed62e4959bb8c01f5975fe81e078e3ff626126; jvm 17.0.10+7
2024-03-24 22:25:03.675:INFO :oejs.DefaultSessionIdManager:main: Session workerName=node0
2024-03-24 22:25:03.800:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started oeje8n.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler@43ed0ff3{ROOT,/,b=file:///C:/Users/james/dev/repo/Celbux/core/target/core-1.0.1/,a=AVAILABLE,h=oeje8n.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler$CoreToNestedHandler@388ffbc2{STARTED}}
2024-03-24 22:25:03.843:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficServerConnector@34abdee4{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{localhost:8080}
2024-03-24 22:25:03.850:INFO :oejs.Server:main: Started oejs.Server@6853425f{STARTING}[12.0.5,sto=0] @1184ms
Mar 24, 2024 8:25:03 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Mar 24, 2024 8:25:03 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Mar 24, 2024 10:25:03 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Mar 24, 2024 10:26:35 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext disableTransportGuarantee
INFO: Ignoring <transport-guarantee> for /* as the SDK does not support HTTPS.  It will still be used when you upload your application.
2024-03-24 22:26:35.892:WARN :oejs.CachingSessionDataStore:qtp988800485-48: Unable to load id jEqKbUfoMcvLuyFaJMXqVw
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call memcache.Get in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:855)
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:183)
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:180)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:107)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:40)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:63)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.MemcacheSessionStore.getSession(MemcacheSessionStore.java:46)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionDataMap.lambda$load$0(MemcacheSessionDataMap.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1195)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.SessionContext.run(SessionContext.java:92)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionDataMap.load(MemcacheSessionDataMap.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.CachingSessionDataStore.load(CachingSessionDataStore.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.loadSession(AbstractSessionCache.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.lambda$getAndEnter$0(AbstractSessionCache.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.NullSessionCache.doComputeIfAbsent(NullSessionCache.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.getAndEnter(AbstractSessionCache.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.get(AbstractSessionCache.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.getManagedSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(AbstractSessionManager.java:1278)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler$CoreSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(SessionHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:803)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler$CoreToNestedHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:2233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:971)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1156)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-03-24 22:26:35.896:WARN :oejs.AbstractSessionManager:qtp988800485-48: Unable to get Session
java.lang.NullPointerException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
        at com.google.appengine.api.NamespaceManager.set(NamespaceManager.java:112)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore$SessionDataStoreImpl.createKeyForSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:209)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore$SessionDataStoreImpl.doLoad(DatastoreSessionStore.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionDataStore.lambda$load$1(AbstractSessionDataStore.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1195)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.SessionContext.run(SessionContext.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionDataStore.load(AbstractSessionDataStore.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.CachingSessionDataStore.load(CachingSessionDataStore.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.loadSession(AbstractSessionCache.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.lambda$getAndEnter$0(AbstractSessionCache.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.NullSessionCache.doComputeIfAbsent(NullSessionCache.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.getAndEnter(AbstractSessionCache.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.get(AbstractSessionCache.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.getManagedSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(AbstractSessionManager.java:1278)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler$CoreSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(SessionHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:803)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler$CoreToNestedHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:2233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:971)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1156)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Mar 24, 2024 10:26:35 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized:
        Type: High Replication
        Storage: C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
Mar 24, 2024 10:26:36 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService load
INFO: Time to load datastore: 29 ms
Mar 24, 2024 10:27:06 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$11 run
INFO: Time to persist datastore: 36 ms
```

When I try access any JSP page:

```json
  ~/dev/repo/Celbux/core  (celbux101)
λ  ./bin/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/bin/dev_appserver.sh target/core-1.0.1/
Warning: unable to determine Java version
Executing [C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot\bin\java, -Dappengine.sdk.root=C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\bin\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java, --add-opens, java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https=ALL-UNNAMED, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -classpath, C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\bin\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar, com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain, --property=kickstart.user.dir=C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core, C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1]
Mar 24, 2024 10:29:28 PM com.google.appengine.init.AppEngineWebXmlInitialParse <init>
INFO: built on 2023-12-28T18:18:01-05:00 from commit ${buildNumber}
Mar 24, 2024 10:29:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\bin\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Mar 24, 2024 10:29:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'appengine.use.EE8', value 'true' with value 'true' from 'C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
2024-03-24 22:29:29.118:INFO :oejs.Server:main: jetty-12.0.5; built: 2023-12-18T14:06:32.502Z; git: 3aed62e4959bb8c01f5975fe81e078e3ff626126; jvm 17.0.10+7
2024-03-24 22:29:29.791:INFO :oejs.DefaultSessionIdManager:main: Session workerName=node0
2024-03-24 22:29:30.027:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started oeje8n.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler@43ed0ff3{ROOT,/,b=file:///C:/Users/james/dev/repo/Celbux/core/target/core-1.0.1/,a=AVAILABLE,h=oeje8n.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler$CoreToNestedHandler@388ffbc2{STARTED}}
2024-03-24 22:29:30.105:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficServerConnector@34abdee4{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{localhost:8080}
2024-03-24 22:29:30.123:INFO :oejs.Server:main: Started oejs.Server@6853425f{STARTING}[12.0.5,sto=0] @2004ms
Mar 24, 2024 8:29:30 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Mar 24, 2024 8:29:30 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Mar 24, 2024 10:29:30 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Mar 24, 2024 10:29:38 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext disableTransportGuarantee
INFO: Ignoring <transport-guarantee> for /* as the SDK does not support HTTPS.  It will still be used when you upload your application.
2024-03-24 22:29:38.771:WARN :oejs.CachingSessionDataStore:qtp988800485-48: Unable to load id 6GytTa8rtKasDzV7fpg45Q
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call memcache.Get in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:855)
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:183)
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:180)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:107)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:40)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:63)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.MemcacheSessionStore.getSession(MemcacheSessionStore.java:46)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionDataMap.lambda$load$0(MemcacheSessionDataMap.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1195)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.SessionContext.run(SessionContext.java:92)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionDataMap.load(MemcacheSessionDataMap.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.CachingSessionDataStore.load(CachingSessionDataStore.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.loadSession(AbstractSessionCache.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.lambda$getAndEnter$0(AbstractSessionCache.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.NullSessionCache.doComputeIfAbsent(NullSessionCache.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.getAndEnter(AbstractSessionCache.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.get(AbstractSessionCache.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.getManagedSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(AbstractSessionManager.java:1278)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler$CoreSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(SessionHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:803)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler$CoreToNestedHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:2233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:971)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1156)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-03-24 22:29:38.776:WARN :oejs.AbstractSessionManager:qtp988800485-48: Unable to get Session
java.lang.NullPointerException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
        at com.google.appengine.api.NamespaceManager.set(NamespaceManager.java:112)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore$SessionDataStoreImpl.createKeyForSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:209)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore$SessionDataStoreImpl.doLoad(DatastoreSessionStore.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionDataStore.lambda$load$1(AbstractSessionDataStore.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ScopedContext.run(ContextHandler.java:1195)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.SessionContext.run(SessionContext.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionDataStore.load(AbstractSessionDataStore.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.CachingSessionDataStore.load(CachingSessionDataStore.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.loadSession(AbstractSessionCache.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.lambda$getAndEnter$0(AbstractSessionCache.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.NullSessionCache.doComputeIfAbsent(NullSessionCache.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.getAndEnter(AbstractSessionCache.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionCache.get(AbstractSessionCache.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.getManagedSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.session.AbstractSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(AbstractSessionManager.java:1278)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler$CoreSessionManager.resolveRequestedSessionId(SessionHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:803)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.nested.ContextHandler$CoreContextHandler$CoreToNestedHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:2233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:971)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1156)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Mar 24, 2024 10:29:38 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized:
        Type: High Replication
        Storage: C:\Users\james\dev\repo\Celbux\core\target\core-1.0.1\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
Mar 24, 2024 10:29:38 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService load
INFO: Time to load datastore: 26 ms
```

If I can have a way to disable or change this thread restriction check, I would be most grateful. As it will mean I can develop via localhost, rather than having to deploy the codebase on each code change.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your `pom.yaml`? Meanwhile check this [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/java-memcache).

Comment: @RoopaM I've added the pom.xml, and read through the full GitHub repo. Not much info I could find relating to my issue (?)

Comment: Have you tried adding the following [dependencies](https://github.com/googleapis/java-memcache?tab=readme-ov-file#quickstart) in your `pom.yaml`?

Comment: @RoopaM Yes, that was the one thing I tried on that page. Unfortunately does not work. Tried both with BOM, and without. Gives exactly the same behaviour for both.